# Find text without any tag in a div element

Tags: php, parsing, html, simple-html-dom

I need to access the 48.20 Lac(s) text which is without any tag inside the div,which is the reason I'm not able to access it.
I need to find this in a PHP file.I've tried $html->find('div.priceDetail') followed with trim(strip_tags($result)) which gave me 48.20 Lac(s) + unnecesary text. 
Since I've to build a generic file I can't depend on exploding and imploding for a particular fixed case.

```
<div class="priceDetail">
    <b>Total Price :</b>
    <img alt="" src="someimage">48.20 Lac(s)
    <!-- Per Sq Ft Price -->
    <span class="pricePerSqFt">(Price per sq.ft. : Rs. 3,679)</span>
    <!-- Code for price Trends -->
    <span class="priceGrowth">4 %
        <img alt="" src="someimage"
        align="absmiddle">
        <span class="iconWhatisThis">
            <img src="someimage"
            class="whatIcon" align="absmiddle">
            <span style="" id="StoolTip" class="price_main-c"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <div class="tt_top-c">
        <span class="priceGrowth"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="tt_mid-c">
        <div class="tt_pointer-c"></div>
        <div>
            <span class="tt_txt-c">Per sq.ft. price for this property is
                <b>higher than the average</b>property price in this locality as per MagicBricks.com
                Price Trends.</span>
        </div>
        <span class="tt_txt-c">
            <span class="tp_txt">To know more about this
                <a href="#priceTrends" onclick="swithTab('priceTrends', tabbedDivArray);">Click
Here</a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tt_bot-c"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a solution with DomDocument, probably more robust than Regex :

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str);

//Get all the image tags
$elem = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');
//Get the first Image
$first = $elem->item(0);
//Get the node after the image
$txt=  $first->nextSibling;
//Get the text
echo $txt->nodeValue;
```

Of course it requires that the text is always located after the first image in the div.

Answer (score 5):

Do as much work as you can with a DOM Parser and then when left with your random load of text, pull the bit out you want with this RegEx:

```
([0-9]{1,5}?\.[0-9]{2} Lac\(s\))
```

Result

```
48.20 Lac(s)
```

*(Change the 5 in the RegEx to the number of digits you want to allow before the decimal point)*